# LocalDateTime to Date

Tags: java, строки, дата, преобразование

Мне нужно конвертировать дату, хранящуюся в переменной типа `LocalDateTime` в формате (*год,месяц,день,час,минута*) в формат миллисекунд, прошедших от от
 1 января 1970 года и присвоить полученное значение переменной типа `Date`. Так же необходимо узнать, как провести обратное преобразование от `Date` в `LocalDateTime`.

```
package myDefault;

import java.time.*;


public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LocalDateTime session = 
            LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.FEBRUARY, 12, 10, 
 30);
        Date sessionInSec = // ?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime session = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.FEBRUARY, 12, 10, 30);
ZonedDateTime zdt = session.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long millis = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();

System.out.println("millis " + millis );
```

Вывод

```
millis 1486924200000
```

Обратно

```
LocalDateTime date =
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis), ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println("date " + date);
```

Вывод

```
date 2017-02-12T18:30
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/4NY72K)